# If we train a binary classifier (lets say tree based) to predict ordinal data do they learn to interpolate?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

Let's assume we have data about students in grade 10. We have test scores ranging from 0-100, however we are only provided two labels ; High score = if the score> 80% and low score if the score < 80%.

Suppose we train a tree-based classifier, will the model learning to interpolate as well? When a calibrated tree is 10% confident that a record (A) is low complexity vs 40% for another record(B) - can we say that record B is likely to have a higher score than record A.

How can we train a model to learn this without explicitly provided the absolute score?

[Edit] - Assume you have freedom to get all the input features you want. Ex: Family income, hours studies etc. in the training set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on data and model fit, it is possible that confidence scores could proxy (relative) predicted performance. However, you cannot guarantee the relationship you describe would occur.

Even if some relationship to this effect does occur, confidence scores would not be easily interpretable. At best you may be able to produce a rough ordering of exam scores, which may produce reasonable results on aggregate. It is unlikely to be suitable for direct comparison of two samples, or for estimating absolute exam scores.

It would be easier to comment further with more information on the desired use case. Also note that this is far less likely to be effective if your model overfits on the training set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have this as the data?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['student'] = [f'student_{i}' for i in range (10)]
df['maths'] = np.random.choice(['high score', 'low score'], size=10)
df['chemsitry'] = np.random.choice(['high score', 'low score'], size=10)
df['physics'] = np.random.choice(['high score', 'low score'], size=10)
df
```

i.e this:
[image]

If yes then I dont think you can do machine learning as there are no features to train on. In this case all you could really do is take percentages of low/high for each and compare (or maybe do ratios).

Comment: Assume you have all the input features you want. Ex: Family income, hours studies etc. in the training set.

Comment: Like the other commenter said, I'm sure you could create models that give probabilities of high score vs low score. But how would you interpret a 50:50 probability vs 30:70. I cannot see how to convert these probabilities into scores reliably. For instance compare a model training on 20 rows for maths but those scores are in reality ~80%, compare this to 20 rows for maths with normal distribution above and below 80%. Your model would predict the same scores even though the original scores are vastly different.